# How to return multiple keys in a string if a given string matches the keys value in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate through a dataframe column to extract a certain set of words. I'm mapping these as key value pairs in a dictionary and have with some help managed to set on key per row so far.

Now, what I would like to do is return multiple keys in the same row if the values are present in the string and these should be separated by a `|` (pipe).

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Red and Blue Lace Midi Dress', 'Long Armed Sweater Azure and Ruby',
                            'High Top Ruby Sneakers', 'Tight Indigo Jeans',
                            'T-Shirt Navy and Rose']})

colour = {'red': ('red', 'rose', 'ruby'), 'blue': ('azure', 'indigo', 'navy')}

def fetchColours(x):
    for key, values in colour.items():
        for value in values:
            if value in x.lower():
                return key
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Colour'] = df['Name'].apply(fetchColours)
```

Output:

```
        Name                            Colour
0       Red and Blue Lace Midi Dress    red
1  Long Armed Sweater Azure and Ruby    blue
2    High Top Ruby Sneakers             red
3        Tight Indigo Jeans             blue
4              T-Shirt Navy and Rose    blue
```

Expected result:

```
        Name                                 Colour
0       Red and Blue Lace Midi Dress         red
1       Long Armed Sweater Azure and Ruby    blue|red
2       High Top Ruby Sneakers               red
3       Tight Indigo Jeans                   blue
4       T-Shirt Navy and Rose                blue|red
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you return directly after finding a key, while you should continue searching untill all results are found:

```
def fetchColours(x):
    keys = []
    for key, values in colour.items():
        for value in values:
            if value in x.lower():
                keys.append(key)
    if len(keys) != 0:
        return '|'.join(keys)
    else:
        return np.nan
```

For this to work you have to change:

```
 colour = {'red': ('red', 'rose', 'ruby'), 'blue': ('azure', 'indigo', 'navy')}
```

to

```
 colour = {'red': ('red', 'rose', 'ruby'), 'blue': ('azure', 'blue','indigo', 'navy')}
```

Because otherwise it won't search for the term 'blue' in each sentence, meaning it cannot add this key to the list in the first example.

Comment: This code should work but somehow it is not, first row should be red|blue but it is only setting red.

Comment: I tried this solution and got the same result as @RehanAzher unfortunately.

Comment: @BobHarris yes and I am unable to find the reason why :)

Comment: The problem is that 'blue' is not one of the values of key 'blue'

Comment: @BobHarris the output is correct, first line  has blue while blue is Key but not in values.

Comment: @Nathan your solution is correct, actually i had it ready but  was trying to find the reason why my output can not match OP expected output.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def fetchColors(x):
    color_keys = []
    for key, values in color.items():
        for value in values:
            if value in x.lower():
                color_keys.append(key)
    if color_keys:
        return '|'.join(color_keys)
    else:
        return np.nan
```